# Difference between Arguments and Inputs in IMethodInvocation

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, unity-interception

What is the different between the `Arguments` collection and the `Inputs` collection in the `IMethodInvocation` interface?

Both are types of `IParameterCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Arguments` collection contains all parameters to the call: in, out and byref.

The `Inputs` collection gets the inputs for this call.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.interceptionextension.imethodinvocation.inputs.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.interceptionextension.imethodinvocation.arguments.aspx

Comment: So would Inputs not contain `out` parameters, or defaults?

Comment: This is all very unclear due to the documentation being deprecated.